# Basic php object creation?

Tags: php, oop

I've got a test script - test1.php:

```
echo "2";
include_once("api_class.php");
echo "3";
$objAPI = new API();
echo "4";
```

api_class.php has:

```
<?php
class API extends DATABASE
{
...
}
?>
```

However, when I access test1.php, I see only:
   23

What am i doign wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't get the class source pasted in, but something must be wrong with your syntax.  Add the following line to the top of your file and it will output verbose error messages that should point you in the correct direction.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, there is an error in api_class.php, more specifically in the API constructor and it is failing. And you have debug/error messages turned off in PHP.

Either turn debug/error messages display on or check your server logs to find the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I 'd guess that the `API` class expects to establish a database connection (maybe configured by constructor parameters?) and calls `die` if it cannot. Which is probably what happens when you try to construct a new `API`.